# Can you be on equal terms with something?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

Does something like "we are all on equal terms" make sense or does it require verbs like "play" or "compete"? "We all compete on equal terms." In school we should write about the advantages of introducing school uniforms and I wrote that "it would contribute to all students being on equal terms" but I dont know if this is optimal or even correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky. It is very clear what you mean, and your use doesn't jump out as wrong -- you have chosen "be" as your verb. However, as you note, it is normal to have a *specific* verb, so this is vague in a way that weakens the writing. What do the students *do* equally?

I suspect that you mean something more specific than "exist" on equal terms. If, for example, you mean that the students will have equal social status, and that this will be reflected through equal social interaction, then you might try something like:

> it would contribute to all students **interacting** on equal terms.

Other options:

- participating
- socializing
- attending
- studying, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> We are all on equal terms.

is correct and understandable as a stand alone statement of egalitarianism.

As alternatives to your uniform sentence, possible are

> School uniforms would *help* contribute to having all students on *more* equal terms.
>   School uniforms would *help* all students to be on *more* equal terms.